# No response when Uncaught exception is thrown on ESB

Tags: wso2, uncaught-exception, wso2-esb

Having some proxy which receives SOAP 1.1 HTTP requests, when some client like soapui sends a request to proxy passing a malformed xml, the ESB throws this exception and this stacktrace appears in the log:

```
[2014-01-22 11:37:54,656] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element <get:GetCapacityRequest>
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,192]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMElementImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getChildren(OMElementImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:553)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    [...]
```

I would like to send back to client some appropriated response, like SoapFault, because in this case the client don't gets any answer and, after some time, it gives timeout.

I configured the `<errorSequence>`, but it don't worked also. There's a way to do this?
I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0.

Comment: Error sequence works, if there are any errors occur in the mediation flow..But here, you are sending an erroneous XML to server. So, it fails when axiom build message.. Do, you want to handle erroneous XML request? I don't think it is possible. Bottom line is, all messages pass through the system should be a valid XML messages.

Comment: Thanks for reply Ratha. Some systems may send incorrect XMLs, and I need to inform to requester what's going on. The SOA suite owned by Oracle do this kind of check and returns a message. I think it's a good improvement to add in WSO2 ESB.